# Unable to Open the application once the windows installer (NSIS) generated the application

Tags: windows-installer, nsis

I have created a PowerTest.NSI file. In this file i have included the required dlls and exes like as shown below and also added the required
commnads.

```
  File E:\Source\PowerTest.exe
  File E:\Source\testutil.dll
  File E:\Source\ntutil.dll
```

Finally I have loaded this NSI script file, it has generated PowerTest.exe

I run this PowerTest.exe and it has generated the below dlls and exes along with uninstall exe in the path (\Program Files\PowerTest)

But when I am running the executable it is not opening the application (It is not responding)

Below is the complete code: (PowerTest.nsi)

```
; PowerTest.nsi
;
;
; It will install PowerTest.nsi into a directory that the user selects.

;--------------------------------

; The name of the installer in the path C:\Program Files\PowerTest
Name "UPowerTestPSTest"

; The file to write  in the path E:\Source
OutFile "PowerTest.exe"

; The default installation directory in the path C:\Program Files\PowerTest
InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\PowerTest

; Registry key to check for directory (so if you install again, it will
; overwrite the old one automatically) It shows the path the path C:\Program Files\PowerTest
InstallDirRegKey HKLM "Software\PowerTest" "Install_Dir"

; Request application privileges for Windows Vista
RequestExecutionLevel admin

;--------------------------------

; Pages

Page components
Page directory
Page instfiles

UninstPage uninstConfirm
UninstPage instfiles

;--------------------------------

; The stuff to install
Section "PowerTest(required)"

  SectionIn RO
  
  DetailPrint "PowerTest"

  ; Set output path to the installation directory. Here is the path C:\Program Files\PowerTest
  SetOutPath $INSTDIR

  ; Give the dll and exe path
  File E:\Source\PowerTest.exe
  File E:\Source\testutil.dll
  File E:\Source\ntutil.dll

  ; Write the installation path into the registry
  WriteRegStr HKLM SOFTWARE\PowerTest"Install_Dir" "$INSTDIR"

  ; Write the uninstall keys for Windows
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PowerTest" "DisplayName" "NSIS PowerTest"
  WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PowerTest" "UninstallString" '"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe"'
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PowerTest" "NoModify" 1
  WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PowerTest" "NoRepair" 1
  WriteUninstaller "uninstall.exe"

SectionEnd

; Optional section (can be disabled by the user)
Section "Start Menu Shortcuts"

  CreateDirectory "$SMPROGRAMS\PowerTest"
  CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\PowerTest\Uninstall.lnk" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" "" "$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe" 0
  CreateShortcut "$SMPROGRAMS\PowerTest (MakeNSISW).lnk" "$INSTDIR\PowerTest.nsi" "" "$INSTDIR\PowerTest.nsi" 0

SectionEnd

;--------------------------------

; Uninstaller

Section "Uninstall"

  ; Remove registry keys
  DeleteRegKey HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\PowerTest"
  DeleteRegKey HKLM SOFTWARE\PowerTest

  ; Remove files and uninstaller
  Delete $INSTDIR\PowerTest.nsi
  Delete $INSTDIR\uninstall.exe

  ; Remove shortcuts, if any
  Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\PowerTest\*.*"

  ; Remove directories used
  RMDir "$SMPROGRAMS\PowerTest"
  RMDir "$INSTDIR"

SectionEnd
```

Please let me know what i have missed. And also do we need to add anything to launch the application? Please suggest if there are any changes from the .nsi text script file i have provided.

Comment: Please only post the code that's relevant to the question. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for details.

Comment: What happens if you just manually copy the files? Does the application work?

Comment: Do you have a UPS connected when you launch this executable? And as Anders asks, does it run properly when you manually copy files in place? Did you check the dependencies for the files?

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `CreateShortcut` call is wrong, it points to a .nsi file. It should point to `$InstDir\PowerTest.exe`.

Your `Delete` call is also wrong, deleting a .nsi makes no sense, it should delete your .exe and .dll files.

NSIS should not make a difference whether your application works or not, the issue is most likely somewhere else. Perhaps you need to register the .dll files or some other configuration change.